# Поиск номеров телефонов и их преобразование

Tags: sql, csv, данные

Всем добрый день!
Есть плоский файл .csv в столбце телефоны могут быть записаны в таких видах (и не только, вариантов куча) (телефон может быть как один, так и несколько через запятую):

+7(495)000-00-00
84950000000
495-00-00
8495-000-00-00, +7 (495) 0000000

И т.д.

Весь .csv в каком он виде есть загружаем в БД.

Каким образом вычленить все отдельные номера (если их несколько в строке через запятую) и разбить их на отдельные строки, при этом чтобы сохранилась связка с владельцем телефона.

А второй шаг их нужно все преобразовать к виду +7495000000.

Записей в таблице миллионы, вручную делать не реально.

Как это сделать? Или может проще преобразования выполнить в файле .csv, и как тогда?

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: В какую БД вы хотите загрузить файл?

Comment: В PostgreSQL будет в итоге

Comment: csv-файлы можно открыть в Excel. Попробуйте открыть их там, разработайте макрос на VBA и исправьте ваш файл. Затем грузите в PostgreSQL.

Comment: Или разработайте расширение для PostgreSQL, которое будет править файл, но это по-моему менее реально.

Comment: Если надо, могу помочь с разработкой программы на VBA для решения этой задачи.

Comment: Глеб, спасибо большое за наводку! Да мне всего лишь надо написать задание для разработчиков, хотела постараться поподробнее расписать, да и самой понять как это сделать.

Comment: Смысл алгоритма должен быть такой: в каждой строке ищете запятую (если она есть), разделяете по ней строку. Затем в каждой строке удаляете все нецифровые символы. И добавляете плюс спереди.

Comment: Глеб, спасибо, то что нужно! Если не сложно, подскажите, что на этом сайте надо сделать, чтобы выбрать Ваш ответ, я второй день здесь)

Comment: Сейчас я перенесу из комментариев в ответ. Там можно щелкнуть слева на стрелку вверх.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

csv-файлы можно открыть в Excel. Попробуйте открыть их там, разработайте макрос на VBA и исправьте ваш файл. Затем грузите в PostgreSQL. Смысл алгоритма должен быть такой: в каждой строке ищете запятую (если она есть), разделяете по ней строку. Затем в каждой строке удаляете все нецифровые символы. И добавляете плюс спереди.

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 1):

В базу писать лучше номера уже в нормальном виде типа 74950000000. Думаю правильно будет сначала разобрать csv с помошью ЯП, которым владеете.

Comment: Спасибо большое!